# How to create insert scripts for tables with FK relationships

Tags: mysql

```
create table foo(id, val1)
create table foo_bars(id, foo_id, val2)
```

id is auto generated in the above case.

I want to do the following

```
insert into foo (val1) values (1)
insert into foo_bars (foo_id, val2) values (?, 2)
```

How do I fetch the value of foo_id if its not known to me. Do I need to hard-code these id(s) also. Is there an elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the mysql site (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Try this (if you want to use pure MySQL):

```
INSERT INTO foo (val1) 
    VALUES(1);         
INSERT INTO foo_bars (foo_id, val2)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),2);  # use ID in second table
```

Comment: Don't forget to use transactions if you use LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: last_insert_id seems simpler. If I have multiple foo_bars for a foo, how would I store the last_insert_id() and re-use it.

Comment: @Felix - How do I use transactions in the above context

Comment: @Joe - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html. Note that transactions are not available using MyISAM (AFAIK)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an elegant way of determing the last inserted id.

check [this for MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) and [this for MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

From their examples:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```